# bourne-shell find-remove

Tags: scripting, sh

I am trying to write a bourne-shell script that takes a string as a parameter and deletes all files in the directory containing that string
I was thinking about using find and execute rm all but I just started b-shell

`find . -name $1 'core' -exec rm -i* {}\;`

any help would be much appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Do you mean the name of the file should contain the string or the content of the file should contain the string?

Comment: @Mithrandir the name of the file sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove.sh script:

```
#!/bin/sh
find . -type f -iname *$1* -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

usage:

```
$remove.sh "main"
```

Comment: It actually remove only the file with the string it doesn't remove the rest of the files

Answer (score 1):

Why not just this:

```
#!/bin/sh
rm *$1*
```

Removes files in the current directory that contain your argument.